# How to find the index of elements of nested tuples by syntax TupleName.index()

Tags: python, indexing, nested, tuples

How to find index of the elements of a nested tuple by index syntax?

For example: I defined my tuple by name NestedTuple

```py
NestedTuple = (5,"jazz",("pop","rock"),(3,4),("disco",(1,2)))  
NestedTuple[4][0]
```

Its output is

```
'disco'
```

But I want to do reverse process that is I want [4][0] as an output by using the syntax TupleNam.index()

```py
NestedTuple.index("jazz")
NestedTuple.index(("pop","rock"))
NestedTuple.index(("disco",(1,2)))
```

The outputs are

```py
1
2
4
```

I tried code like TupleName.index(("disco")) etc but none of them is working.
How can I get the index of "disco" as [4][0] by using index syntax?
I am new to the programming language and at beginners level so whoever is going to answer please use basic things only?

Comment: is `NestedTuple` a class that you wrote?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own recursive function that will return all indices of any given element in a nested tuple like the above:

```
NestedTuple = (5,"jazz",("pop","rock"),(3,4),("disco",(1,2))) 

def findIndices(item, tup):
     indices = []
     for index, elem in enumerate(tup):
          if item == elem:
               indices.append(index)
               return indices
          elif isinstance(elem,tuple):
               indices.append(index)
               return indices + findIndices(item,elem)

print(findIndices('pop',NestedTuple))
```

This will return:

```
[2, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping . But at present I am not that much familiar to all these things. I thought there may be inbuilt function which will give my desired output!.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to provide your own implementation for such thing.

Comment: Thanks for advice and I will apply this type of techniques.